# I don't understand why my list's value is reset

Tags: python

```
N,M=map(int,input().split())

ans=[]
lst=[]

def dfs(num):
    global ans
    if(num==M):
        ans.append(lst)
        return

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        if(i not in lst):
            lst.append(i)
            dfs(len(lst))
            print(ans)
            lst.pop()
            print(ans)

dfs(0)

print(ans)
```

this is my code.
This is example code, when I put N=4, M=1.
[execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc6ha.png)

I don't understand why my list called ans is reset, when after 'lst.pop()'
Two lists are actually seperated lists.
Thank you

Comment: *"Two lists are actually seperated lists."* They actually aren't. When you do `ans.append(lst)`, that means that `ans` contains the `lst` object itself, not a copy of `lst`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment

Comment: It might help if you included in your question the expected result for your example.

Comment: Try it on http://pythontutor.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ans.append(lst) uses the reference of 'lst', so when you do lst.pop(), the change is reflected in 'ans' also. You need to create a copy of the 'lst', i.e. ans.append(lst.copy())

```
N,M=4,1

ans=[]
lst=[]

def dfs(num):
    global ans
    if(num==M):
        #Appending a copy of the 'lst' List
        ans.append(lst.copy())
        return

    for i in range(1,N+1):
        if(i not in lst):
            lst.append(i)
            dfs(len(lst))
            print(ans)
            lst.pop()
            print(ans)

dfs(0)

print("Final:",ans)
```

> output

```
[[1]]
[[1]]
[[1], [2]]
[[1], [2]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
Final: [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```